# change to new price but should not affect calculation with old price In Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of customers and there price of the product. I want to change the price anytime might be once in a month or once in three months or once within 15 days. I keep changing according to the market demand. my need is that my old price calculation should not affect with new price in google sheet. kindly help me with best formula or suitable link where it fulfill my need

Comment: How can people help you without having seen a sample of your data structure? The purpose for you in using this platform should be to show what you've done so far and point out where you're stuck. "Experts" as you say will have a look, and most likely they will help you. By doing so, you will gain 2 things: solve your problem and gain in knowledge. So please share a sample of (dummy) data that represents your situation, show what you've tried and what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank You Nabnub for immediate Reply. I am sending you the link, Hope it is understandable. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jYOmu9Aen6CvSlu9b0rZQkqvkJqmIiU60T4DW0-6-nc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first intuition should be to find how to lookup for the price for a particular customer against the table of prices you've set up for each product: so your first choice is to use the function `VLOOKUP` to find (vertically) the the customer in your table, then to use `HLOOKUP` to find (horizontally) the product, both together will give you the matching price. But now you have another problem: being able to change the price from time to time. You could use a simple approach (which avoids dates manipulations), by adding another criteria in your `VLOOKUP` search, which can be something like **PRICE ID**:
and keep it very simple: A,B,C,D...etcc for any new price. Meaning before the date, you will choose which price should be considered for the row that you're entering data for.

So to get the **RATE**:

```
= ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(K5:K) * LEN(M5:M), VLOOKUP(L3 & K5:K, {
    $B$4:$B & $A$4:$A,
    $C$4:$I
}, match(M5:M, $B$4:$I$4, 0), 0), ))
```

To get the **AMT**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(N5:N),N5:N*O5:O,))
```

**Spreadsheet Demo: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jYOmu9Aen6CvSlu9b0rZQkqvkJqmIiU60T4DW0-6-nc/edit#gid=160986284)**

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much Nabnub. I was Busy with other Stuff could not be online. really this worked. some more changes I did to my work . I need your help again. I will be back with some more quarries, thanks a LOT .